# How to edit user group list without reentering password in glassfish?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, user-administration

I have users in my file realm assigned to several groups on GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1. I want to change user Group List to give or take away some roles. Glassfish admin console requires re-entering password when I edit user settings, so I have to remember (write down somewhere) all user passwords and reenter them just to keep it the same. Is there a way to avoid this? Maybe I'm missing something about managing users, because I'm a beginner in java-ee development?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where is the code problem in this question?

Comment: Thank you, @THeron! I see, I asked it in wrong community... :) Probably should try in ServerFault? SO is my "default knowledge base", so I came here, but this question is indeed not about coding.

Comment: Correct - try asking in ServerFault or SuperUSer instead.

Comment: I think this question fits here. It is a question about ["software tools commonly used by programmers"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using file realm you can edit keyfile located in glassfish/domains/your-domain/config directory. Probably server should be restarted after editing it, didn't test it, because:

More convenient way is to use [JDBC Realm](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-advanced003.htm) for authentication and user management. User credentials and groups are stored in database and may be treated as objects with JPA.